# How to filter django serializer fields?

Tags: python, django, filter, serialization

I have question about Django REST FRAMEWORK.

```
class UserTest(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='usert', null=True, blank=True)
    question = models.ForeignKey(Question, related_name='userque', on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True)
    option = models.ForeignKey(Option, related_name='opt', on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.user.username + ' - ' + self.question.question
```

**This is my model for UserTest**. And when ever user gives test. The user will see all questions in drop down as well as all options. But I want only the options of which question user choose. But now i get all of the options.

```
class TestSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    question = serializers.SlugRelatedField(queryset=Question.objects.all(), slug_field='question')
    option = serializers.SlugRelatedField(queryset=Option.objects.all(), slug_field='option')

    class Meta:
        model = UserTest
        fields = ('question', 'option')
```

**This is my Test serializer.**

```
class Question(models.Model):
    lesson = models.ForeignKey(Lesson, related_name="lquestion", on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True)
    question = models.TextField()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.question
```

This is my question model

```
class Option(models.Model):
    question = models.ForeignKey(Question, related_name='choices', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    option = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    is_correct = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.option + ' - ' + self.question.question
```

This is my option model.

I hope you got the question i m trying to ask. When user selects the question. I want to display only the options of that questions in drop down. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Add your Question model to your code. I also don't understand the thing about the drop down and what user chose. Could you elaborate on that more.

Comment: I have added Question and Option model @Dimitar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The model structure isn't correct. The `Test` HAS `questions`. The `Questions` have `options`.

Remove `option` in the `UserTest` model then remove the `question` from the `Option` model.

I don't know what `lesson` is, it make more sense to be `UserTest` here but I am gonna leave it because I don't actually know your structure.

```py
class Question(models.Model):
    lesson = models.ForeignKey(Lesson, related_name="lquestion", on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True)
    question = models.TextField()
    options = models.ManyToManyField(Option)
    
    def __str__(self):
        return self.question
```

Your `Option` Model should not have any other relations.

Here is how to serialize it later: https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/